# Sysgcc: ld.exe cannot find -lcurl -ljsoncpp

Tags: c++, windows, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I'm working on a project on a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B. I started coding and compiling directly on the Pi and now I want to work on a Windows 7 PC. I already installed the SysGCC Cross-Compiler and managed to compile a simple Hello-World program.
Problem is, for my Project i use curl and jsoncpp. Natively on the Raspberry i have no problems compiling it, but the cross-compiler on Windows gives me following error:

```
c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcurl
c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ljsoncpp
```

I don't use a makefile or so because i never really worked with that and on the raspi it just worked fine with this command:

```
g++ ../src/rpi/main.cpp ../src/rpi/connection.cpp ../src/rpi/jsonparser.cpp ../src/rpi/idchecker.cpp ../src/rpi/eventoperator.cpp -o ../bin/main -lcurl -ljsoncpp
```

On the Windows system i tried it with a command like this:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.exe -std=c++11 ../src/rpi/main.cpp ../src/rpi/connection.cpp ../src/rpi/jsonparser.cpp ../src/rpi/idchecker.cpp ../src/rpi/eventoperator.cpp -o ../bin/main -L"C:/SysGCC/raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include/jsoncpp/json/" -L"C:/SysGCC/raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/curl/" -lcurl -ljsoncpp
```

So i read that i have to tell the compiler/linker where the libraries are, but i don't really understand why since it works perfectly without the -L flag on the Raspi. I think i put the libraries in the same folder as on the Raspi, so i don't understand why they are not found. I hope someone can help me ore give me some short basic explanation on how this stuff works, cause i don't find any working tutorial or other helpful questions for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

On raspberry-pi the libraries are most likely to be linked from system directory like `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`. On Windows, you need to specify the correct path(s) with -L flag.

Comment: As you can see in the last command, that is exactly what i did/what i tried to do. I think the folders i linked there are some kind of "simulated" Raspi environment by the cross-compiler, since it automatically finds these files, but somehow still finds the libraries..

Comment: Oh sorry, i mixed the directories up a little bit. But the directiories i linked with the -L flag are the ones actually used by my raspi, so i don't understand why the cross compiler doesn't find them.

Comment: It should find it automatically only if the paths are specified in LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable or somehow like this